# Ассоциативный массив vs класс

Tags: массивы, структуры-данных, классы, алгоритм, python

Недавно начал разбираться с python и парсингом на нем и обратил внимание, что большинство получаемой информации можно как записать в ассоциативный массив по типу:

```
{'name': 'MySite', 'url': 'http://mysite.com'}
```

так и унаследоваться от предварительно созданного класса:

```
class Site:
    def __init__(self, name, url):
        name = name
        url = url
```

Как с классом, так и с ассоциативным массивом можно выполнять примерно один набор операций (из тех, что мне нужно) - добавить сайт в массив всех сайтов, получить/записать сайт.
Что и в каких случаях (если отойти от вопроса парсинга) лучше использовать? Кто что вообще думает по этому поводу и какие варианты еще возможны/уместны?

Comment: @zesudageg, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

dict, сам по себе, будет обрабатываться быстрее (хотя бы потому, что класс сам по себе подразумевает underlying dict, хоть и есть всякие трюки co slots, позволяющие ускорить работу и уменьшить потребление ресурсов), однако использование класса в некоторых случаях просто необходимо. Если очень грубо - надо использовать dict там, где содержание может сильно варьироваться или вообще неизвестно, а также где данные сами по себе представляют пары ключ-значение (например, перевод на конкретный язык: переводимая строка => переведенная строка, больше у единицы информации ничего нет, кроме этих двух сущностей), во всех остальных случаях использовать класс. Если чуть подробнее:

Класс нужно использовать в тех случаях, когда

- Подразумевается хотя бы минимальная логика (проверка типа, конвертация значений).
- Логика *может* появиться. В этом случае лучше положить соломы заранее.
- Передаваемые данные структурированы и представляют собой конкретную сущность, т.е. это какой-то многократно используемый набор данных, чья структура жестко определена. Например, пишется приложение мобильного оператора - в этом случае у нас наверняка будет такая сущность как сим-карта - у нее есть поля список мобильных номеров, PIN, PUK, ICCID, ID владельца и т.п. В этом случае класс нужно использовать для того, чтобы формализовать конкретные поля, получить автокомплит в IDE и точно знать, к чему обращаться в той или иной части приложения. Формально - это структура из C, которая не выполняет никакой логики, но конкретно эта структура закрепляется с помощью класса.

Преимущество, которое приносит класс - это именно возможность жестко задать необходимые поля. Языку наплевать с чем работать, но с точки зрения архитектуры это очень важное свойство.

Прошу прощения, что у меня такие проблемы с вербализацией.

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае использовать словарь (ассоциативный массив) выгодней с точки зрения потребеления памяти.

С классом можно добавить всякие удобные фичи, например, реализовать методы `get_prepared_url` и `get_upper_name`, которые будут приводить в порядок url (проверять, есть http или нету, поставили слеш в конце или нет и т.п.) и возвращать name в верхнем регистре. Таким образом вы можете "спрятать" часть логики в классе и сделать код более красивым.

К тому же у классов есть механизм [слотов](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots), который позволит приблизить их по потребелению памяти к словарям.

Если захотеть еще больше экономить память, то можно использовать [tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple) (кортеж):

```
data = ('MySite', 'http://mysite.com')
```

Это почти как список, только еще экономней. Но тогда нам придется обращаться к элементам по их индексам: 0, 1, а это не очень удобно. Тут нам на помощь прийдет [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
from collections import namedtuple
site_record = namedtuple('SiteRecord', 'name url')
mysite = site_record(name='MySite', url='http://mysite.com')
print mysite.name, mysite.url
```

Он позволяет хранить данные в памяти, как обычный кортеж, но доставать их по именам.

В общем, если вам нет смысла заморачиватся ни с памятью, ни с красотой кода, а нужно просто и быстро реализовать алгоритм - используйте словарь.
Если хотите красиво и удобно - используйте классы.
Если хотите очень экономно - попробуйте кортежи.

Comment: В питоне самым распространенным является подход с классами? Как лучше писать, чтобы потом не стыдно было показать исходники?

Comment: В питоне (как и везде) самым распространенным является разумный подход.

Если разумно использовать словарь - используйте его, если больше подходит класс - воспользуйтесь им.

Ничто из этого не является постыдным.

Ответьте себе на вопрос - что я выиграю если использую класс? Если ответ - ничего или мифическая красота кода в скрипте, который никто, кроме вас, не увидит, это плохой вариант. Если же вы четко понимаете, зачем вам именно класс, вам будет что ответить тем, кто критикует ваш код.

Также давайте не будем забывать, что словарь это так же экземпляр класса. {} это то же самое, что dict(

Comment: @LinnTroll, за мифической красотой кода обычно скрывается правильная архитектура, которая очень многое решает при первом же рефакторинге.

Comment: @Etki, ни в коем случае с вами не спорю. Говорю лишь о том, что надо понимать, нужна ли конкретно в этом проекте правильная архитектура и будет ли там вообще когда-нибудь рефакторинг.

Написанный на коленке за полчаса одноразовый парсер, который сожрет 16гб озу и будет выполнятся 2 часа и завалится при любой неожиданности лучше идеального парсера, который отработает за пару минут на любой машине и учтет любые исключительные ситуации, но писаться будет неделю.

Comment: > нужна ли конкретно в этом проекте правильная архитектура

нужна

> и будет ли там вообще когда нибудь рефакторинг.

рефакторинг начинается не тогда, когда надо добавить новые фичи, а когда оказывается, что у тебя компоненты зависят друг от друга, и каждый надо проинициализировать раньше другого, а стадия инициализации вообще пропущена нупотомучтоэтопрототип, или парсер работает в несколько стадий, и умирает после первой стадии, которая заняла полтора часа (реальный случай из практики)

Я этот пример уже в миллиардный раз слышу. Но реально прототипы сильно по времени не выигрывают.

Comment: ясно, всяко бывает.

Comment: Спасибо большое @Etki и @LinnTroll, внесли ясность и понимание!

Comment: Без измерений, за исключением `types.SimpleNamespace`, я бы не стал утверждать, что меньше места занимает - миллион объектов: dict, namedtuple, или своего класса со `__slots__`. Результаты также могут зависеть от версии Питона.